# subset of Measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is a measurable mapping from one measurable space $S$ to another measurable space $U$. If $A$ is a measurable subset of $S$, does it follow that the image $f(A)$ is a measurable subset of $U$?

Comment: This does not follow even if $f$ is continuous. You can consider the Cantor function $c(x)$ on $[0,1]$ and set $f(x) = c(x) + x$. The function $f$ is continuous and strictly monotone increasing, so it has a continuous inverse, call it $g$.  Any subset of the Cantor set has measure zero, hence is Lebesgue measurable. However, $f$ maps the Cantor set $C$ onto a set of positive measure. Thus, $f(C)$ contains a non-measurable subset, $N\subset f(C)$. Then $g(N)$ is the sought-after set.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is subsets of middle Cantor set that your image by the Cantor funtion is not borel measurable. You can find comments of this for example in "An introduction to measure and integration" of Inder K Rana.

Comment: But Cantor function is Lebesgue  measurable

Comment: In fact, it is continuous.